# layerslider autoplayvideos not working

Tags: slideshow

I am unable to get autoPlayVideos and autoPauseSlideshow to work. I pasted my code below. The show works flawlessly, it just won't autoplay the video or pause the show. Is this incorrect usage of these parameters? Or has anyone heard of compatibility problems with other scripts or libraries causing this?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
            navPrevNext         : false,
            skinsPath : 'assets/layerslider/layerslider/skins/',
            skin : 'fusionskin',
            autoPlayVideos : true,
            autoPauseSlideshow : true,
        });
    });
```

Also, if I change autoPauseSlideshow from true to auto, the slideshow doesn't work at all - just blank. What am I doing wrong?